# Typescript [React] not converting .tsx imports to .jsx imports

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I keep typescript react components in different files, so I use the following statement to import my sub components.

//app.tsx

```js
import {SideBar} from "./sidebar"
```

But when typescript compiles app.tsx to app.jsx, the import statement switches to require("sidebar"). I get an error on the javascript as the require statement needs to have "sidebar.jsx" with ".jsx" extension. Is there a way I could automate that?

My tsconfig setting is :

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "jsx": "preserve",
        "target": "ES5",
        "noImplicitAny":false,
  "module": "commonjs",
        
    }
}
```

Maybe I need to add something to the tsconfig file?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps put all `.tsx` files in a separate folder, entirely?

Answer (score 0):

## Option 1

> I get an error on the javascript as the require statement needs to have "sidebar.jsx" with ".jsx" extension.

Fix this error e.g. if you are using webpack you can add `.jsx` as a resolvable path.

```
resolve: {
  // Add `.jsx` as a resolvable extension.
  extensions: ['', '.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.jsx']
},
```

If so maybe even use ts-loader : https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-loader and not have `jsx: preserve` and instead `jsx: react`. More : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/jsx/tsx.html

## Option 2

Use `module: es6` instead of  `"module": "commonjs",` and typescript will not rewrite `import` to `require`.